# ASP.NET regular expression, restricting numbers

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

My problem is following, i have to write regular expression, that will forbid strings, that consist only of numbers. For now i have:

```
@"^\D{3,30}$"
```

But it won't match something like `qwe2`. So, in other words, i need regular expression, that:

- Checks if number of symbols is between 3 and 30
- allow all symbols
- Deny input if string consists of numbers only

E.g. `qwe/{}21''@3` - good; `123` - bad; `ab` - bad.

Comment: You need to specify conditions clearly. You want every symbol to be present ? How is `ab` bad ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a password validator? Then you should probably require that the number of symbols is between 12 and 200 or more. 30 is far, far too short a max number and 3 is nothing - even 6 is too small nowadays. 30 will prevent people from using secure passphrases and force them to use insecure short passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative lookahead `^(?!\d+$)` would make the match fail of the input consists of digits only. The rest is obvious:

```
^(?!\d+$).{3,30}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ACeHB7/1

Comment: Just to be sure, it works like - If `something on the left` is not a number -> string fits the expression?

Comment: If `something on the right of the begin of the string` is not a number then a string consisting of at least of 3 and at most 30 chars will fit the expression.